# Default Radio option sselected

Tags: radio-button, opencart

I need set a default Radio button selected on opencart 2.3 using javascript
[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb5Mr.png)
[Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPKzs.png)

```html
<div class="radio" style="margin-top: -5px;"><!--EOF Related Options-->
                  <!--BOF Related Options--><label for="option-value-2492"><!--EOF Related Options-->
                    <!--BOF Related Options-->
     <input type="radio" name="option[590]" value="2492" id="option-value-2492" master-option-value="0" option-value="115">
     <!--EOF Related Options-->
                                        
                    Comprar par                                      </label>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add checked="checked"

`<input type="radio" name="option[590]" value="2492" id="option-value-2492" master-option-value="0" option-value="115" checked="checked">`

Comment: No work, you can see here https://msgoldjoias.com.br/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=120